# (python) Parsing certain HTML output tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Hello :) After playing around for a bit, I've come up with the following function, which returns the full HTML tag, rather than simply the part in inverted <*>"this"<*>

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

def get_wotd():
    return str((BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.reference.com/wordoftheday'))).findAll('h2'))

print get_wotd()
```

Today's word, for instance is "nosh". Instead of getting:

```
[<h2 class="me">nosh</h2>]
```

I need the output to be, simply,

```
nosh
```

Anyone got any idea how I could pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text` attribute to fetch inner-text, and use `find()` method instead:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.reference.com/wordoftheday'))
>>> soup.find('h2').text
u'nosh'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lxml` instead of BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from lxml.html import parse
>>> tree = parse("http://www.reference.com/wordoftheday")
>>> tree.xpath("//h2")[0].text
'nosh'
```

Comment: Reason for using lxml is simple: I don't have BeautifulSoup installed on my Mac, it seems.